# I am getting an error when I install Docker

Tags: docker, centos, installation

I've already installed the docker, it worked just fine.I am now trying to install the Centos operating system, but I get the error constantly. The error is below.

```
+ sh -c 'yum install -y -q docker-ce'

Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/docker from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/docker from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-attach.1.gz from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-checkpoint-create.1.gz from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-checkpoint-ls.1.gz from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-checkpoint-rm.1.gz from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-checkpoint.1.gz from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-commit.1.gz from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-config-create.1.gz from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-config-inspect.1.gz from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-config-ls.1.gz from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/docker-config-rm.1.gz from install of docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64
.............
```

Comment: Try installing with version number . I think its conflicting with version number .

`docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-ce-cli-0:18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7.x86_64`

Comment: thank you I solved the error, uninstalled and reinstalled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the installed version of `docker-ce-cli` is `18.09.0.ce-1.1.beta1.el7`, which is newer than the version of the `docker-ce` package you are trying to install, `18.06.1.ce-3.el7`.  The `docker-ce` packaging is not prepared for that.

You will have to downgrade or remove `docker-ce-cli` before installing the `docker-ce` package.

Comment: thank you I solved the error, uninstalled and reinstalled